# filter and save first X lines of a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I'm using pySpark to read and calculate statistics for a dataframe.

The dataframe looks like:

```
TRANSACTION_URL    START_TIME        END_TIME           SIZE    FLAG  COL6 COL7 ...
www.google.com     20170113093210    20170113093210     150      1    ...  ...
www.cnet.com       20170113114510    20170113093210     150      2    ...  ...
```

I'm adding a new `timePeriod` column to the dataframe, and after adding it, I would like to save the first 50K records with `timePeriod` matching some pre-defined value.

My intention is to save those lines to CSV **with the dataframe header**.

I know this should be a combination of `col` and `write.csv` but I'm not sure how to properly use those for my intentions.

My current code is:

```
encodeUDF = udf(encode_time, StringType())
log_df = log_df.withColumn('timePeriod', encodeUDF(col('START_TIME')))
```

And after the column has been added i'm guessing I should use something like:

```
log_df.select(col('timePeriod') == 'Weekday').write.csv(....)
```

Can someone please help me fill the blanks here, to match my intentions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`unix_timestamp` and `date_format` are useful methods here as `START_TIME` is not timestamp type.</strike>

```
dfWithDayNum = log_df.withColumn("timePeriod", date_format(
  unix_timestamp(col("START_TIME"), "yyyyMMddHHmmss").cast(TimestampType), "u")
)
```

`timePeriod` will have the **day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)**

```
dfWithDayNum
  .filter(col("timePeriod") < 6) //to filter weekday
  .limit(50000) //X lines
  .write.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("location/to/save/df")
```

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't needed as i have my own `encode_time` UDF as you can see (which returns a string for the date + hours, as those are my requirements). Regarding `filter, limit` I've also managed to solve it using those, you're missing the `option("header", "true")` I was also looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved using `filter()` and `limit()` methods in the following way:

```
new_log_df.filter(col('timePeriod') == '20161206, Morning').limit(50).write.\
    format('csv').option("header", "true").save("..Path..")
```